# What is the best practice to architecture (folder structure) enterprise level React web application, using redux and redux-saga as middleware?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, directory-structure

Any changes required with my current folder structure? Is components based or atomic level based folder structure is preferred?

```
.
├── App.css
├── App.js
├── App.test.js
├── assests
├── components
│   └── button.js
├── constants
├── helpers
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── pages
│   ├── action.js
│   ├── homePage.js
│   ├── reducer.js
│   └── saga.js
├── routes
├── services
└── serviceWorker.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why go with Atomic design?

1. Separation of Concerns.
2. Component re-usability.
3. Simplified testing.
4. Scalability.
5. Uniformity.
6. Configurability.

**Atoms:**
Basic building blocks of matter, such as a button, input or a form label. They’re not useful on their own.

**Molecules:**
Grouping atoms together, such as combining a button, input and form label to build functionality.

**Organisms:**
Combining molecules together to form organisms that make up a distinct section of an interface (i.e. navigation bar)

**Templates:**
Consisting mostly of groups of organisms to form a page — where clients can see a final design in place.

**Pages:**
An ecosystem that views different template renders. We can create multiple ecosystems into a single environment — the application.

**Containers**:
A container does data fetching and then renders its corresponding sub-component

***File Structure***:

```
└── src
    ├── actions
    │   └── action.js
    ├── App.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── atoms
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── molecules
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   ├── organisms
    │   │   └── index.js
    │   └── templates
    │       └── index.js
    ├── index.js
    ├── pages
    │   └── home
    │       └── HomeComponent.js
    │       └── HomeContainer.js
    ├── reducers
    │   └── index.js
    ├── resources
    │   └── img
    │       └── logo.svg
    ├── routes.js
    ├── sagas
    │   └── index.js
    ├── serviceWorker.js
    ├── setupTests.js
    ├── store.js
    └── tests
        └── application.spec.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go fo a specific store folder. This is the way I would structure the project:

```
.
├── ...
├── components
│   └── containers
│       └── someConnectedComponent.js
│   └── presentational
│   └── UI
│       └── button.js
├── store
│   └── actions
│   └── middleware
│       └── index.js
│       └── some.saga.js
│       └── another.saga.js
│   └── reducers
└── ...
```

- The components that are connected to Redux go in container folder.
- Their children (non-connected) go in presentational folder.
- The reusable components go in UI folder inside presentational.
- Redux has it's own specific folder, and Saga goes inside the middleware folder.

As Redux is used as the single source of truth, the right way is to split the concepts: on one hand, you have the components, and on the other, all the business logic in Redux + Saga. The application logic is not mirrored with the logic in Redux Saga, so it makes more sense to separate into their own folders (for example, it can be the case that some container components use multiple reducers).

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective, you may place action, reducer and saga independently, like you have to take out from page folder because on that folder should be contains only page like login page.